# How to filter speckle noise?

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am trying to remove a speckle noise from an image, all my research is pointing me at using a Knox-Thompson method, developed by astronomers, but I can't find any information about it, much less an algorithm.
What is Knox-Thompson method and what algorithm does it use?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: Should I delete and re-phrase my question then?

Comment: You can probably just re-phrase it, no need to delete it, since it's getting upvotes and answers regardless

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at despeckle plug-in od GIMP
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/despeckle.c

Also, despeckling implementation in Scantailor
https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/tree/f1711c941ea0a6d78b07f714d5ff33715ba33491/filters/output